# Splash screen redirecting wrong Activity android

Tags: android, redirect

Basically i have a handler for a splash page which redirects to the main menu after 5 seconds.

However, i also have a settings page which is seen on a first time setup, but whats happening is that it is thinking this is a splash page and is redirected after x seconds. I need this to not redirect on x seconds, just need the splash screen 'MainActivity' to redirect.

Main Problem:

First time setup loads Preferences.
Problem: It redirects after 5 seconds.

Whats supposed to happen:
First time setup loads Preferences.
Allows user to enter details and save.
On next launch, splash page appears which redirects after 5 seconds.

Heres is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, 5000);

        // get shared preferences
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        // first time run?
        if (pref.getBoolean("firstTimeRun", true)) {

            // start the preferences activity
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Preferences.class));

            //get the preferences editor
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

            // avoid for next run
            editor.putBoolean("firstTimeRun", false);
            editor.commit();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Unable to understand your question. And you don't need to context of an Activity to start a intent.

Comment: Don't use vague terms, specify the exact problem !

Comment: added a better description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rearranged your code to say what you want to happen.

> Whats supposed to happen: First time setup loads Preferences. Allows user to enter details and save. On next launch, splash page appears which redirects after 5 seconds.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);
        // get shared preferences
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        // first time run?
        if (pref.getBoolean("firstTimeRun", true)) {
            // start the preferences activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Preferences.class));
            //get the preferences editor
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            // avoid for next run
            editor.putBoolean("firstTimeRun", false);
            editor.commit();
        } else {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sort of fixes it, what happens after the settings it goes to the splash screen which doesnt redirect. How can i say after the Preferences menu it loads up MainMenu

Comment: If you want to load mainmenu after preference then override onactivityresult in main activity and load main menu( when child activity finishes parent onactivityresult is called)

Comment: Am confused how do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand ,this should solve your problem

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int REQUESTCODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);
    Toast.makeText(this, "MainActivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // get shared preferences
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    // first time run?
    if (pref.getBoolean("firstTimeRun", true)) {

        // start the preferences activity
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(getBaseContext(),Preference.class), REQUESTCODE);

        // get the preferences editor
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        // avoid for next run
        editor.putBoolean("firstTimeRun", false);
        editor.commit();

    } else {
        startMainMenu();
    }

}

public void startMainMenu() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    MainMenu.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, 5000);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUESTCODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            startMainMenu();
        }
    }
}
}
```

In your Preference activity after set the preference call function 'setResult()'

```
public class Preference extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
/**
Add necessary preferences to shared preference
**/

if(sharedPreference successfully entered){
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
}else{
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
}
finish();
```

}

For more details http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

I hope this helped you...

Comment: No didnt work :( after saving preferences, just gets stuck on the splash screen. Doesnt go to MainMenu

Answer (score 0):

Did u try setting activity result in preference activity as RESULT_OK

Comment: No dont know what to do